# optimize sql query

Tags: sql, optimization, oracle11g

I have a monster legacy query that is in the core of my program,
the query takes too much time , what is the best way to make it run faster ? 
I use oracle 11g

```
 SELECT   *
     FROM     ( SELECT  COUNT(*) AS countme,
                       string_value        ,
                       name                ,
                       property_id         ,
                       category_id
              FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT a.string_value,
                                        a.name        ,
                                        a.property_id ,
                                        b.product_id  ,
                                        a.category_id
                       FROM             filter_criterias a
                                        JOIN product_properties b
                                        ON              (
                                                                          a.property_id = b.property_id
                                                         AND
                                                                          (
                                                                                           (
                                                                                                            isnumber(b.value)        IS NOT NULL
                                                                                           AND              isnumber(a.range_bottom) IS NOT NULL
                                                                                           AND              isnumber(a.range_top)    IS NOT NULL
                                                                                           AND
                                                                                                            (
                                                                                                                             a.range_bottom >a.range_top
                                                                                                            AND              b.value       >= a.range_bottom
                                                                                                            OR               a.range_bottom<=a.range_top
                                                                                                            AND              b.value       >= a.range_bottom
                                                                                                            AND              b.value       <=a.range_top
                                                                                                            )
                                                                                           )
                                                                          )
                                                         )
                                        JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY prc
                                        ON               (
                                                                          prc.sku         = b.product_id
                                                         AND              prc.category_id = a.category_id
                                                         )
                                        JOIN PRODUCT pr
                                        ON               (
                                                                          b.product_id = pr.SKU
                                                         AND              pr.visible   = '1'
                                                         )
                       )
              GROUP BY (string_value, name, property_id,category_id)

              UNION

              SELECT   COUNT(*) AS countme,
                       string_value       ,
                       name               ,
                       property_id        ,
                       category_id
              FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT a.string_value,
                                        a.name        ,
                                        a.property_id ,
                                        b.product_id  ,
                                        a.category_id
                       FROM             filter_criterias a
                                        JOIN product_properties b
                                        ON              (
                                                                          a.property_id = b.property_id
                                                         AND
                                                                          (
                                                                                           (
                                                                                                            a.name= b.value
                                                                                           )
                                                                          )
                                                         )
                                        JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY prc
                                        ON               (
                                                                          prc.sku         = b.product_id
                                                         AND              prc.category_id = a.category_id
                                                         )
                                        JOIN PRODUCT pr
                                        ON               (
                                                                          b.product_id = pr.SKU
                                                         AND              pr.visible   = '1'
                                                         )
                       )
              GROUP BY (string_value, name, property_id,category_id)
              )
     ORDER BY 5,4,3,2
```

this is the explain plan

```
    "Optimizer" "Cost"  "Cardinality"   "Bytes" "Partition Start"   "Partition Stop"    "Partition Id"  "ACCESS PREDICATES" "FILTER PREDICATES"
"SELECT STATEMENT"  "ALL_ROWS"      "1298"  "2"         "542"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"SORT(ORDER BY)"    ""              "1298"  "2"         "542"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"VIEW"              ""              "1297"  "2"         "542"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"SORT(UNIQUE)"      ""              "1297"  "2"         "74"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"UNION-ALL" ""      ""              ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""
"HASH(GROUP BY)"    ""              "661"   "1"         "37"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"VIEW"              ""              "659"   "1"         "37"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"HASH(UNIQUE)"      ""              "659"   "1"         "95"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"NESTED LOOPS"      ""              ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"NESTED LOOPS"      ""              "658"   "1"         "95"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"HASH JOIN"         ""              "493"   "1"         "81"    ""  ""  ""  ""B"."PRODUCT_ID"=TO_NUMBER("PRC"."SKU") AND "A"."CATEGORY_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C("PRC"."CATEGORY_ID")" ""
"HASH JOIN"         ""              "369"   "2"         "128"   ""  ""  ""  ""B"."PROPERTY_ID"=TO_NUMBER("A"."PROPERTY_ID")"    ""A"."RANGE_BOTTOM">"A"."RANGE_TOP" AND "A"."RANGE_BOTTOM"<=TO_NUMBER("B"."VALUE") OR "A"."RANGE_BOTTOM"<="A"."RANGE_TOP" AND "A"."RANGE_BOTTOM"<=TO_NUMBER("B"."VALUE") AND "A"."RANGE_TOP">=TO_NUMBER("B"."VALUE")"
"TABLE ACCESS(FULL) BNET.B_FILTER_CRITERIAS"    "ANALYZED"  "36"    "28"    "1148"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""ISNUMBER"(TO_CHAR("A"."RANGE_BOTTOM")) IS NOT NULL AND "ISNUMBER"(TO_CHAR("A"."RANGE_TOP")) IS NOT NULL"
"TABLE ACCESS(FULL) BNET.B_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES"  "ANALYZED"  "332"   "12566" "289018"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""ISNUMBER"("B"."VALUE") IS NOT NULL"
"TABLE ACCESS(FULL) BNET.WLCS_PRODUCT_CATEGORY" "ANALYZED"  "124"   "129762"    "2205954"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"INDEX(RANGE SCAN) BNET.WLCS_PROD_VISIBLE_IDX"  "ANALYZED"  "12"    "6208"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""PR"."VISIBLE"='1'"    ""
"TABLE ACCESS(BY INDEX ROWID) BNET.WLCS_PRODUCT"    "ANALYZED"  "164"   "1" "14"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""B"."PRODUCT_ID"=TO_NUMBER("PR"."SKU")"
"HASH(GROUP BY)"    ""              "637"   "1"         "37"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"VIEW"              ""              "635"   "1"         "37"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"HASH(UNIQUE)"      ""              "635"   "1"         "91"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"HASH JOIN"         ""              "634"   "1"         "91"    ""  ""  ""  ""B"."PRODUCT_ID"=TO_NUMBER("PRC"."SKU") AND "A"."CATEGORY_ID"=SYS_OP_C2C("PRC"."CATEGORY_ID")" ""
"NESTED LOOPS"      ""              ""      ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"NESTED LOOPS"      ""              "509"   "1"         "74"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"HASH JOIN"         ""              "345"   "1"         "60"    ""  ""  ""  ""B"."PROPERTY_ID"=TO_NUMBER("A"."PROPERTY_ID") AND "A"."NAME"="B"."VALUE"" ""
"TABLE ACCESS(FULL) BNET.B_FILTER_CRITERIAS"    "ANALYZED"  "35"    "11257" "416509"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"TABLE ACCESS(FULL) BNET.B_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES"  "ANALYZED"  "309"   "251319"    "5780337"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"INDEX(RANGE SCAN) BNET.WLCS_PROD_VISIBLE_IDX"  "ANALYZED"  "12"    "6208"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""PR"."VISIBLE"='1'"    ""
"TABLE ACCESS(BY INDEX ROWID) BNET.WLCS_PRODUCT"    "ANALYZED"  "164"   "1" "14"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""B"."PRODUCT_ID"=TO_NUMBER("PR"."SKU")"
"TABLE ACCESS(FULL) BNET.WLCS_PRODUCT_CATEGORY" "ANALYZED"  "124"   "129762"    "2205954"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

Comment: Impossible to tell, because we don't know what indexes exist. Showing the explain plan might be a good start...

Comment: @Daniel - even without the plan I could see numeric values being stored as strings due to ISNUMBER.  And that is causing TABLE SCANs.  And that's like trying to inflate a hot-air balloon by eating beans and holding a zippo in a conspicuous place.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I don't think this question is too localized.  Although there are a lot of details that aren't important to others, the core issue of storing numbers as strings applies to a large audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One potentially *massive* source of problem is that you are having to use ISNUMBER.

If you store numeric values as text, and then use operations such as "x <= y", you accomplish a lot of negative things:
- The string has to be parsed in to a number before it's used
- A string's index can potentially bear no resemblence to a numeric's index
- If the index is useless, you get table scans rather than index seeks

I would highly recommend looking at storing the values as real numbers, not as strings.  The combination of not having to use ISNUMBER, not having to convert each value, and so actually being Able to use an index can have extreme performance benefits.

**EDIT**

The PLAN you just added includes a lot of instances of `TABLE ACCESS(FULL)` and several of those appear to be associated with numeric values being stored as strings.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by making it a little more readable by at least indenting it. If you can't read it, you cannot optimize it. You can make it more readable by using aliases that match the table name, so `filter_criterias` becomes `fc` instead of `a`. In the query below, I just corrected the outlining a little and got rid of excess parentheses.

```
SELECT   
  *
FROM  
( 
    SELECT  
        COUNT(*) AS countme,
        string_value,
        name,
        property_id,
        category_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.string_value,
            a.name,
            a.property_id,
            b.product_id,
            a.category_id
        FROM
            filter_criterias a
            INNER JOIN product_properties b
                ON a.property_id = b.property_id
                AND isnumber(b.value) IS NOT NULL
                AND isnumber(a.range_bottom) IS NOT NULL
                AND isnumber(a.range_top) IS NOT NULL
                AND ( 
                    a.range_bottom > a.range_top
                    AND b.value >= a.range_bottom
                    OR a.range_bottom <= a.range_top
                    AND b.value >= a.range_bottom
                    AND b.value <=a.range_top
                )
            INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY prc
                ON prc.sku = b.product_id
                AND prc.category_id = a.category_id
            INNER JOIN PRODUCT pr
                ON b.product_id = pr.SKU
                AND pr.visible = '1'
    )
GROUP BY
    string_value, 
    name, 
    property_id,
    category_id

UNION

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS countme,
    string_value,
    name,
    property_id,
    category_id
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.string_value,
        a.name     ,
        a.property_id ,
        b.product_id  ,
        a.category_id
    FROM
        filter_criterias a
        INNER JOIN product_properties b
            ON a.property_id = b.property_id
            AND a.name = b.value
        INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY prc
            ON prc.sku = b.product_id
            AND prc.category_id = a.category_id
        INNER JOIN PRODUCT pr
            ON b.product_id = pr.SKU
            AND pr.visible = '1'
    )
GROUP BY
    string_value, 
    name, 
    property_id,
    category_id
ORDER BY 5,4,3,2
```

After you've done that, you'll notice that it contains to queries, separated by a UNION. If these queries each contain different rows, you could use UNION ALL. Just UNION, will perform another DISTINCT on the result, which is slower.

Also, those two subselects are almost the same, except for a single condition in the join of product_properties b (check by putting each subselect in WinMerge or a similar tool). So maybe you can skip the union at all, and combine the two conditions in an OR in the join, although you must remember that OR will slow down the joins!

These kind of problems wil emerge when you look at the explain plan of your query. It's always good to look at it to see which joins give you problems. Sometimes it is just a forgotten index. But it is important to know that some operations slow down the query, like using OR in a join (which you do), using DISTINCT when it's not needed and using UNION where you can use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1):

Step through the execution plan and see where the bottlenecks are. Right off the top, here's a few things you can look into:

- Don't use SELECT * - select the specific columns you need.
- Examine joins and see if there's any way you can make them more efficient
- Replace nested queries with derived tables wherever possible
- Use SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of the query
- Make sure all tables are properly indexed

You definitely need to look at the execution plan though, and go from there.

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON` in Oracle???

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should look at in an explain plan is the cardinality (the estimated number of rows).  The optimal plan to return 1 row is usually very different than the optimal plan to return 1 billion rows.  If Oracle's estimate is significantly wrong you need to try to figure out why it is wrong and what you can do about it.

I agree with @Dems that ISNUMBER is likely the cause of your problems, but for different reasons.  Oracle cannot accurately guess how many rows will be filtered out by predicates with a custom function.  Although you may know that 99.9% of the rows will pass that filter, Oracle assumes that only 5% will pass.  This leads to a very low cardinality, which leads to inefficient nested loops instead of hash joins.

You can give the optimizer more useful information by creating extended statistics on the ISNUMBER function.  This assumes you are on Oracle 11g, and that ISNUMBER is deterministic:

```
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(null,'product_properties','(isnumber(value))') from dual;
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(null,'filter_criterias','(isnumber(range_bottom))') from dual;
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(null,'filter_criterias','(isnumber(range_top))') from dual;

--Must re-gather table stats for the extended stats to work
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_Table_stats(user, 'product_properties', no_invalidate => false);
    dbms_stats.gather_Table_stats(user, 'filter_criterias', no_invalidate => false);
end;
/
```

However, your second query doesn't use ISNUMBER and still has an estimated cardinality of 1.  Are your table and index statistics up to date?  Check `select last_analyzed, table_name from user_tables;`.  Or it may be that Oracle just won't ever get the estimates right.  A hint like /*+ no_use_nl(a b prc pr) */ may help.

Also, it looks like you're trying to implement short circuit logic in SQL, but this will not always work.  Oracle does not necessarily process the predicates top to bottom, and you may find that one day your query fails when the plan changes.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

1. Make sure you have the right indexes created and up-to-date
2. Make sure no implicit type conversions are performed (`pr.visible   = '1'` looks like one such case)